# Find Polygon in “Layer A” containing Polygon in “Layer B”

Tags: pyqgis

I have two layers:

- Region Layer
- Postcode Layer

both containing multi-polygon features.

I would like to cycle through all the Postcodes, find which is the Region that contains that Postcode, and eventually write the ID of the region inside the Postcode.

So far I've tried to write something in the Python Console, which I can share here:

```
from qgis.utils import iface
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant
_ID_FIELD = 'RS'
_NAME_FIELD = 'GEN'
_PLZ_FIELD = 'plz'
_NEW_ID_FIELD = 'PARENT_ID'
_NEW_NAME_FIELD = 'PARENT_NAME'
Land_layer = iface.mapCanvas().layer(1)
PLZ_layer = iface.mapCanvas().layer(0)
# Create 2 new fields in the layer that will hold the list of neighbors and sum
# of the chosen field.

#PLZ_layer.startEditing()
#PLZ_layer.dataProvider().addAttributes(
#        [QgsField(_NEW_ID_FIELD, QVariant.String),
#         QgsField(_NEW_NAME_FIELD, QVariant.Int)])
#PLZ_layer.updateFields()

## Create a dictionary of all features
PLZ_feature_dict = {f.id(): f for f in PLZ_layer.getFeatures()}
Land_feature_dict = {f.id(): f for f in Land_layer.getFeatures()}
# Build a spatial index
index = QgsSpatialIndex()
print 'PLZ Layer: %s' % PLZ_layer.name()
print 'Landkreis Layer: %s' % Land_layer.name()

for f in Land_feature_dict.values():
    index.insertFeature(f)
    print 'Inserting %s in Landkreis index' % f[_NAME_FIELD]

for f in PLZ_feature_dict.values():
    print 'Working on %s' % f[_PLZ_FIELD]
    geom = f.geometry()
    intersect_ids = index.intersects(geom.boundingBox())
    for id in intersect_ids:
        tempf = Land_feature_dict[id]
        print 'got parent Landkreis %s' % tempf[_NAME_FIELD]
```

Problem is, I'm getting the following error at line

```
intersect_ids = index.intersects(geom.boundingBox())


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "//VAIMUCO9/G114305$/Anwendungsdaten/Desktop/PLZ/ContainerFinder.py", line 34, in  <module>
    intersect_ids = index.intersects(geom.boundingBox())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'boundingBox'
```

Moreover, I'm not really sure that I should use these functions, and even this approach.

Can you suggest a more clever way?

Answer (score 2):

A few things. First, .getFeatures() returns an iterator, and not the features themselves, so putting them in a dictionary is only good to consume memory.

I re-did your work using a couple of layers I have for the Phoenix, AZ area and it worked well. See below.

The original code also does NOT guarantee that the feature is contained, but rather that it intersects. I included a test to make sure it intersects.

I did not worry about names, since mine would be different than yours, but the code works and you can add the messages to it.

```
PLZ_layer = iface.mapCanvas().layer(0)
Land_layer = iface.mapCanvas().layer(1)


# Build a spatial index
index = QgsSpatialIndex()
for f in Land_layer.getFeatures():
    a=index.insertFeature(f)

print 'PLZ Layer: '+ PLZ_layer.name()
print 'Landkreis Layer: '+ Land_layer.name()

for f in PLZ_layer.getFeatures():
    geom = f.geometry()
    intersect_ids = index.intersects(geom.boundingBox())

    #Now we filter only the IDS that intersected our f feature
    request = QgsFeatureRequest()
    a=request.setFilterFids(intersect_ids)

    #And we will loop through them in order to see which actually contain our f feature
    for feat in Land_layer.getFeatures(request):
        if feat.geometry().contains(geom):
            print 'FOUND A FATHER'
```